# Can I invoke the Kotlin noargs plugin from the command line or from Ant?

Tags: ant, annotations, kotlin, kotlinc

Kotlin has a [noarg compiler plugin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#no-arg-compiler-plugin) which can be used to generate synthetic no-argument constructors for specially-annotated classes. The documentation page clearly explains how to use it with Maven and Gradle, but it is not clear whether it can be used, or how to use it, either from Ant or using `kotlinc` on the command line.

So far I've been unable to make it work. Here's my `NoArgs.kt` source file:

```
package test

annotation class NoArgs

@NoArgs data class Test(val x: String, val y: String)
```

And here are some command lines I've tried, which have no effect at all:

```
$ kotlinc -verbose "-Xplugin:$KOTLIN_HOME/lib/noarg-compiler-plugin.jar -P plugin:org.jetbrains.kotlin.noarg:annotation=test.NoArgs NoArgs.kt
```

and:

```
$ kotlinc -verbose "-Xplugin=$KOTLIN_HOME/lib/kotlin-annotation-processing.jar;$KOTLIN_HOME/lib/noarg-compiler-plugin.jar;$JRE_HOME/lib/tools.jar" -P plugin:org.jetbrains.kotlin.noarg:annotation=test.NoArgs NoArgs.kt
```

When I run `$ javap test.Test` there is no evidence of a generated no-args constructor. There's some side-evidence that the plugin isn't running at all, as well, in the fact that if I put garbage instead of the word *annotation* for the **-P** option, there's no error message or change in behaviour.

If you can tell me how to get it to run using `kotlinc` or from Ant, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: It seems everything I ask on SO these days gets a downvote. Can the person who voted me down explain the defect in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the path to the `noarg-compiler-plugin.jar` file.
This works for me (Kotlin 1.1.3-2 from [Homebrew](https://brew.sh)):

`kotlinc-jvm -Xplugin=$KOTLIN_HOME/libexec/lib/noarg-compiler-plugin.jar -P plugin:org.jetbrains.kotlin.noarg:annotation=test.NoArgs NoArgs.kt`

```
Compiled from "NoArgs.kt"
public final class test.Test {
  public final java.lang.String getX();
  public final java.lang.String getY();
  public test.Test(java.lang.String, java.lang.String);
  public final java.lang.String component1();
  public final java.lang.String component2();
  public final test.Test copy(java.lang.String, java.lang.String);
  public static test.Test copy$default(test.Test, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, int, java.lang.Object);
  public java.lang.String toString();
  public int hashCode();
  public boolean equals(java.lang.Object);
  public test.Test();
}
```

Comment: Not working for me (on Windows, either via `cmd.exe` or Cygwin's bash shell). I'm also using Kotlin 1.1.3-2. I've checked and double-checked the JAR path at least a zillion times. I'll try it on a pure Linux VM later today.

Comment: As an update, I'm able to make it work on Linux just by downloading the [Kotlin 1.1.3-2 release](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/releases/tag/v1.1.3-2) and running the same command that I provided in my question and you provided in your answer. So something is broken w Windows. Once I figure this out, I'll accept your answer and amend my question to provide the details about Windows-y-ness.